# Why previous ecert and keys are still valid after restarting fabric network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Following fabcar sample tutorial ([Writing Your First Application](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html)) I've registered and enrolled 'user1' user by admin ecert. So keys and eCert of 'user1' was saved in 'hfc-key-store' subdirectory. Using 'user1' identity material I read data from ledger using query.js script.

After that, I want to launch the network again, so kill all docker containers, clear docker images, networks and volumes. But identity materials ('hfc-key-store') were not destroyed. After relaunching the network I try to query ledger data with **previous** 'user1' identity material, and it works fine. I can't understand why old 'user1' ecert is still valid after restarting network? What fabric component should check if ecert is enrolled by fabric-ca? After relaunching I don't enroll admin for fabric-ca, so 'user1' is also not registered.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fabcar sample network config used pre-generated certificates and key material that means the root cert of fabric-ca remains the same, so previous 'user1' identity material is still valid. If you regenerate root cert, access with previous certs will be denied.